# Can't define std::function variable from the virtual method pointer in vs2013

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013

In my project I am trying to define std::function variable from the virtual method pointer:

```
#include <functional>
class VirtualClass
{
public:
  virtual void foo(int x) = 0;
};

class DerivedClass : public VirtualClass
{
public:
  virtual void foo(int x) override
  {
    // I am foo from DerivedClass;
  }
};

int main()
{
  DerivedClass derivedClass;
  std::function<void(VirtualClass&, int)> fooFunc = &VirtualClass::foo; //doesn't compile
  fooFunc(derivedClass, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

This code is compiling in visual studio 2017, but doesn't compile in visual studio 2013. Is it possible to fix a compilation error in vs 2013 without switching to pure pointers and keep using std::function?

**update:**

the error message is the following:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,VirtualClass &,int>::_Set(std::_Func_base<_Ret,VirtualClass &,int> *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Ret,VirtualClass &,int> *'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional   506 1   ConsoleApplication1

Comment: This seems like a good case for lambdas, or perhaps `std::bind` instead.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Quentin I've updated the question. Included there the error message

Comment: It builds with VS 2015 as well. A lot has changed in both the compiler and Standard Library since VS 2013. Why not just upgrade to the newer conformant compiler? Note that in VS 2013, ``<functional>`` doesn't work with the ``__vectorcall`` convention, but it does in VS 2015+.